# Uncountable set of uncountable equivalence classes

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find $A/\sim$, a set $A$ with an equivalence relation $\sim$ such that the set of equivalence classes is uncountable and the equivalence classes contain an uncountable amount of elements.

I already tried with $A = \Bbb{R}$ and $x \sim y := x - y \in \Bbb{Z}$. The equivalence classes are the sets of reals with the same fractional part. You can show that $A/ \sim = [0,1)$. Which is easy to show is uncountable with an injection $f: \{0,1\}^{\infty} \to [0,1)$ (this is the standard method I use to show a set is uncountable).

However, I think all elements in my equivalence classes are countable, as they are all natural numbers plus a specific fractional part. Am I right to think like this, does it make my example false ? In case it is false, is there a way to "fix" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers have already given concrete examples. Here's something more abstract that you can do. Let $I$ be any uncountable set and let $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of uncountable sets. Define the $$A := \{(a, i) : i \in I, a \in A_i\}.$$
In other words, the above is the disjoint union $\sqcup_{i \in I} A_i$. Define the relation $\sim$ on $A$  by $$(a, i) \sim (b, j) \Leftrightarrow i =j.$$
Then, the equivalence classes are precisely the copies of $A_i$, i.e., $A/{\sim} = \{A_i \times \{i\} : i \in I\}$.

In some sense, this is the most general way of getting an uncountable set of uncountable equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you, this method is very interesting as it mainly uses the fact that equivalence are disjoint, and works from there.

Comment: @BrockenDuck Indeed, in fact, if I had started with the collection $\{A_i\}_i$ to be disjoint, to begin with, then I wouldn't have to do that $(a, i)$ thing and I could've simply taken the union.

Answer (score 5):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, define $(x,y) \sim (a,b)$ iff $x = a$. Equivalence classes are copies of $\mathbb{R}$, and there are "$\mathbb{R}$" of them (one per $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 5):

You are right that you have uncountably many equivalence classes, but each equivalence class is only countably infinite.

It is easier to find relations with uncountably many uncountably large classes on the plane $\Bbb R^2$.

It might also be easier to go the "other way". Build the equivalence classes first as an uncountable collection of uncountable, disjoint sets, and define the relation as "Two elements are related iff they are in the same set."

Comment: I was thinking about the set of all circles with center 0, as every circle is an uncoutable amount of points and there are an uncountsble amount pf circles, this definitely works. However, finding the injections from $\{0,1\}^{\infty}$ would be pretty hard

Comment: It's not accurate to say that the "standard method" is finding an injection of $\{0,1\}$. Instead, it is completely appropriate to find an injection of *any* set that is well known to be uncountable.

Comment: Continuing with Lee's comment: @BrockenDuck note that you have an injection from $(0, \infty)$, which is known to be uncountable. (Minor note: You need to take care of the origin somehow.)